# What is the Google API password for the OAuth PKCS p12 private key?

Tags: api, passwords, pkcs#12

The Google API setup provides a way to create a project with a service account.

I download the private key as a PKCS #12 p12 file.

Where do I find the password for this file?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Answer: **notasecret**

https://developers.google.com/console/help/#service_accounts

Your application needs the private key when requesting an OAuth 2.0 access token in server-to-server interactions. Google does not keep a copy of this private key, and this screen is the only place to obtain this particular private key. When you click the "Download private key" button, the PKCS #12 formatted private key is downloaded to your local machine. As the screen indicates, you must securely store this key.

The name of the downloaded private key is the key's thumbprint.

When inspecting the key on your computer, or using the key in your application, you will need to provide the password **notasecret**. Please note that while the password for all Google-issued private keys is the same (notasecret), each key is cryptographically unique.

Comment: so, How to use that password ?? I mean what is the syntax ?

Comment: @Anil there are many ways, one is `openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -nodes -nocerts > key.pem`, then type in `notasecret` when prompt

Comment: Note: the Google documentation seems to have to https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#serviceaccounts It currently states:

_Note that while the password for all Google-issued private keys is the same (notasecret), each key is cryptographically unique._

Also, the p12 way of setting up service account auth with google services is somewhat deprecated in favor of JSON service keys.