# Unable to delete events in Google Calendar using php api

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am working on the PHP API to Google Calendar, I have previously used the Zend library and I am upgrading to the API V3 I downloaded the Git Hub client library v1.0.
I have completed oAuth 2 and I am storing Refresh tokens in a database. I can connect and write events to Google Calendar, thanks mainly to the contributors at StackOverflow. Thanks

My problem is that I cannot delete events. I am connecting with oAuth 2 and retrieving event Ids however

```
    $service->events->delete('primary', $event->getId());
```

This generates Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect: '0'' in C:\wamp\www\new-roster-decoder\src\Google\IO\Stream.php on line 128

I have hunted high and low and been unable to find a solution. Please help Thanks

EDITED AS SOLVED
Due to Emily's great advice this is solved
Solution downloaded the latest API from GitHub as the problem of GZIP has been sorted.
As a matter of interest I initially commented out GZIP in congig.php and this fixed it, but I then lost the performance benefits, then new library sorted it.
Lessons learnt. Stackoverflow users are very kind to give their time, and always try the lastest software
END OF EDIT

```
   <?php
    /// This works

    session_start();

    set_include_path("src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/Calendar.php';
    require_once 'account/dbc.php';



    $client_id = 'XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    $client_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
    $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:80/new-roster-decoder/account/GoogleoAuth.php';


    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
    $client->setAccessType('offline');


    $users_rs_settings = mysqli_query($link,"select * from users WHERE id = 118");
    $users_array = mysqli_fetch_array($users_rs_settings);

    $refresh_token = $users_array['refresh_token'];  //2010-04-06
    $client->refreshToken($refresh_token);

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();  
    $event->setSummary('Positioning TX');
    $event->setLocation('BRS-LGW');

    $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime('2014-02-19T14:00:00.000-00:00');
    $start->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
    $event->setStart($start);
    $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime('2014-02-19T17:25:00.000-00:00');
    $end->setTimeZone('Europe/London');
    $event->setEnd($end);
     // insert ext properties
    $rdname = "RosterDecoderID";
    $rdvalue = 1;

    $extendedProperties = New Google_Service_Calendar_EventExtendedProperties();
    $extendedProperties->setPrivate(array($rdname=>$rdvalue));
    $event->setExtendedProperties($extendedProperties); 

    // end of insert ext properties

    $createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);   
    echo $createdEvent->getId()."\n\n"; 

    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    var_dump($_SESSION['access_token']);
    var_dump($event);

    $minCheck = date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y") ));
    $maxCheck = date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), (date("d")+1), date("Y") ));

    $optParams = array( 'privateExtendedProperty' => 'RosterDecoderID=1','timeMin' => $minCheck, 'timeMax' => $maxCheck);
    $events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $optParams);





   while(true) {
       foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
        $eventID = $event->getId();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //This bit throws an error
        $service->events->delete('primary', $event->getId());
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // The error is
    // Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect: '0'' in C:\wamp\www\new-roster-decoder\src\Google\IO\Stream.php on line 128


         echo $event->getSummary();
         echo $event->getId()."\n\n"; 
      } 
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Hey this looks like it might be related to the php client library.  check out this thread and see if it helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428180/google-analytics-api-v3-http-error-unable-to-connect-on-live-server-localhos

Answer (score 0):

I am able to delete event from google calendar..

use private key file you get from developer console.

Fore more info check this link

[What is the Google API password for the OAuth PKCS p12 private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534438/what-is-the-google-api-password-for-the-oauth-pkcs-p12-private-key)

[how-where-to-obtain-a-p12-key-file-from-the-google-developers-console](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58411/how-where-to-obtain-a-p12-key-file-from-the-google-developers-console)

below is code please check

```
const KEY_FILE = '<<some location on server>>/xxx-65454f656a-xxx-560265d-privatekey.p12';
// this is my private key file location, make sure it accessible 


try {
            $key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);     
            $auth = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
                    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
                    $key);
            $auth->sub = $calendarId;
            $client = new \Google_Client();
            $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
            $client->setApplicationName("Parabola V2");
            $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
            $service = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
            $service->events->delete($calendarId, $eventId);            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "Exception while deleting event :- ".$e->getMessage();
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$service->events->delete('primary', $event->getId());
```

'primary' must be the calendar id

"myname@gmail.com" or "mhggf54gfh5@group.calendar.google.com"
thats how it work for me